# Why does'nt calling Finish() immediately close my activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

So here is my scenario.

1. Activity1 launches - my splash screen displays
2. User clicks SignOn button
3. SignOn Activity runs - SignOn Screen display
4. User Enters user id and password, clicks submit button
5. If userid and Passwod valid a StartActivity to FeaturesMenu activity is executed, got step-7
6. Userid and Password invalid, message set in textview in view in SignOn Screen, enters correction and clicks submit button or clicks cancel button and Finish() is called.
7. FeatureMenu Activity runs and displays list of buttons for the user to click.
8. User clicks button to list Bloodpressure readings from an SQLite DB, cursor.
9. A StartAcitvity for BloodPressList Activity is run.
10. The cursor is then bound to a customCrusor adapter and listview
11. The screen associated with the BloodPressure List Activity display a list of rows one for each reading entry by day. Or a blank screen if there is no data returned to the cursor.In either case a button labeled done is displayed on the bottom of the screen.
12. When the user clicks the Done button the Blood Pressure List Activity Screen should go away and the Features Menu Screen should return. This is so the user can now select some other feature. btw, the Done button does nothing except call Finish(). What actually happens is the Blood Pressure List Activity Screen blinks and stays on display. When I click done again it finally goes away and the Feature Menu Displays.

What gives? Why doesn't the call to Finish immediately take me back to Features Menu. Why do I need to click Done button twice?

Comment: I would read the code, but this, meh.

Answer (score 0):

You must have two instances of the Blood Pressure List activity.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're starting two instances of the ListActivity, my guess is that you're doing something strange either in steps 8-9 or step 11. But you'll have to post some code for us to really help you.

Comment: thanks for your responses. I have discovered the solution. I added the attribute NoHistory=true to those activities that will be doing a StartActivity(typeof(AuthUser) for example. Then, in this example, when AuthUser activity for example finds the user authorized, it does a StartActivity(typeof(FeaturesMenu). Note: I also save any data I need to refer to in other StartActivitys in Preferences.